# Не работает подчиненный запрос

Tags: c#, sql, access

Нужно выбрать самое дорогое лекарство.

```
Select  Назва, Ціна from Ліки where Ціна > all(Select Ціна from Ліки)
```

Выводятся пустые поля.
[image]

Скриншот таблицы

Comment: по сабжу, можно сделать индекс по цене, отсортировать и взять первый. Второй вариант, сначала найти максимальную цену, потом выбрать соответствующий продукт.

Comment: А мой запрос таки неверный ?

Comment: есть еще варианты, с джойнами и т.п., это можно найти среди вопросов по выборке строки с максимальным значением. Это довольно частая задача.

Comment: Ваш запрос, мне не совсем понятно на каком диалекте написан. Если это чистый SQL, то что такое `all` ? 
Напишите его в виде `Select  Назва, Ціна from Ліки where Ціна = (Select max(Ціна) from Ліки)` и будет работать.

Я  не очень хорошо знаком с диалекотом MS Access.

Comment: @arakul Ваш текущий запрос ищет записи у которых цена не самая большая, а больше, чем чем самая большая. Да сделайте как в комментарии выше цена равна максимальной

Comment: Большое спасибо. Аж стыдно стало, что туплю. А возможно ли это сделать как-то через all ?

Comment: @teran Кстати, такой синтаксис (all) поддерживает большинство СУБД, просто он малоизвестный

Comment: @arakul с помощью `>all` сделать не получиться, т.к. максимальное значение уже находится среди этих all, вероятно, вам поможет `>= all()`, тогда должно остаться единственное значение.

Comment: @Mike, да прочитал доки уже. Видел его и раньше, просто забывается такое, ибо действительно, крайне редкое.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @teran, не могли бы вы мне помочь с еще одним запросом ?

Comment: @arakul дак создавайте новый вопрос (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Назва, Ціна FROM Ліки
WHERE Ціна = (SELECT MAX(Ціна) FROM Ліки)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно "ORDER BY Ціна LIMIT 1" - получите именно то, что требуется.

Comment: Нужно именно через подчиненный запрос.

Comment: Select  Назва, Ціна from Ліки where Код in (SELECT Код from Ліки ORDER BY Ціна DESC LIMIT 1)

Comment: Иисус Христос, зачем нужна группировка, порядок сортирования по убыванию и LIMIT для поиска полей с максимальным числом.

Comment: @Kryshtop О группировке речи тут не идет. А вообще этот вариант имеет право на жизнь, тем более, что в определенных случаях он быстрее подзапроса

Comment: Сортировка*. извиняюсь.

Comment: @Kryshtop то есть зачем вообще нужен вложенный запрос, вас не интересует :)